# Flutter Riverpod: Using ref.watch Outside of Build Function

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In my Flutter app, I have a function gotoPage() that animates a PageView widget to a new page.  I'd like this function to be called whenever newPageProvider is updated. How do I "activate" the ref.watch() inside the function gotoPage() when gotoPage() is not part of build() function?

providers.dart

```
final newPageProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);
```

widget.dart

```
class _WidgetState extends ConsumerState<WidgetState> {

  final pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return WidgetCard(poi: data[index], itemIndex: index);
      },
    );
  }

  void gotoPage() {
    final index = ref.watch(newPageProvider);
    pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show where you define your pageController?

Comment: @JCRC.  Now showing the pageController.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is use ref.listen, not ref.watch (as shown below).

From the [RiverPod user guide](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-reflisten-to-react-to-a-provider-change):

> Similarly to ref.watch, it is possible to use ref.listen to observe a
> provider.
>
> The main difference between them is that, rather than
> rebuilding the widget/provider if the listened provider changes, using
> ref.listen will instead call a custom function.

> The listen method should not be called asynchronously, like inside onPressed or
> an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles.

providers.dart

```
final newPageProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);
```

widget.dart

```
class _WidgetState extends ConsumerState<WidgetState> {

  final pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.listen<int>(newPageProvider, (int previousIndex, int newIndex) {
      _gotoPage(newIndex);
    });
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return WidgetCard(poi: data[index], itemIndex: index);
      },
    );
  }

  void gotoPage(index) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Use `ref.listen` in `build()` instead.

Like so:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 ref.listen(
   newPageProvider,
   (oldIndex, newIndex){
     pageController.animateToPage(newIndex);
   }
 );
 return Scaffold(...);
}
```

Comment: Hi Josteve, thank you.  But when newPageProvider is updated, what logic would call gotoPage()?  Where would the logic be located?  When ref.watch is in build(), no problem.  But gotoPage() is not part of build().  I feel like there is something simple here that I am missing.

Comment: You use gotoPage to programmatically go to a new page, is that part of your requirement?

Comment: Yes.  When newPageProvider has a 'new value', I would like pageController.animateToPage(new value).  But it seems with Riverpod, ref.watch needs to be in the Widget build()?  And the gotoPage() function above is not part of the Widget.build() function.  This does not seem an unusual use-case.  I can see the identical issue, for example, with a GoogleMapController and wanting to update map markers by watching a Riverpod Provider holding map points.  How do you code a widget controller to watch a Riverpod provider?  I guess that is the basic question.

Comment: Hi Josteve, not sure if that works, but putting ref.listen in initState conflicts with the RiverPod user guide.  Which states "The listen method should not be called asynchronously, like inside onPressed or an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles."

Comment: Oh Oh, Okay...Putting it in build method should work then.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: This code is not working .. Why ?? any reason .?

Comment: What error do you have?